# ExecuteMso error

Tags: vba, excel

This question may have been asked before.

I have tried using ExecuteMso in VBA but returns Method or data member not found.

Not sure what I am doing wrong or if there is an issue using this code as using excel on a Mac. I have also tried this on a windows version of Excel however it is a very old version (if that makes a difference?)

Any help or tips regarding this would be great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following sample executes the Copy button.

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso(“Copy”)
```

---

Otherwise, post what you have tried and what is giving you the problem.

Comment: Hi. I have tried this with a newer version and it worked fine so I am putting it down to the version i was using. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Could you kindly up-vote my answer and/or mark it as the answer?

Comment: What version are you working with? I'll see if I can find an equivalent.